# Make the whole body of an HTML page clickable

Tags: javascript, html, clickable

This is not a really difficult question, but how do you make the whole webpage clickable? I need this for my website
I want that if you click anywhere a file is downloaded.

```
 body {
     ifclickanywhere - download file
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
<body onclick="window.location.href=filename">
body text
</body>
```